# Distribution of $Y = \frac{1}{X} + X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As in the title, I am trying to get the distribution of $Y = \frac{1}{X} + X$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval (0, 1).  I am having trouble seeing how to move beyond what (very little) I have so far:

$$P(Y\leq y) = P(\frac{1}{X} + X \leq y) = P(\{x: \frac{1}{x} + x \leq y\}) \\
= P(\{ 1 + x^2 \leq xy \}) = P(\{ x^2 - xy + 1 = 0\})
$$

Comment: 1) $\leq$ changed to $=$ in your last line. 2) If you multiply by negative number, $\leq$ should change to $\geq$.

Comment: @xyzzyz I'm sorry, I really don't follow at all why you did (1) and how (2) helps me.

Comment: @learner, how to continue: Solve that quadratic inequality for $x$ so you have $P(f(y) \leq X \leq g(y)) = P(X \leq g(y)) - P(X < f(y)) = F(g(y)) - F(f(y))$, where $F$ is the distribution function of $X$. You know $F$, now you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \qquad x + \frac 1 x = y \\[6pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & \qquad x^2 + 1 = xy \\[6pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & \qquad x^2 - yx + 1 = 0 & \text{(a quadratic equation)} \\[6pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & \qquad x = \frac{y \pm \sqrt{y^2 - 4}} 2
\end{align}
We need $0<x<1$, so we choose $\text{“}{-}\text{''}$ rather than $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$.

No if you can show that $x+ \dfrac 1 x$ decreases as $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$, that deals with the inequality $(1)$ below. And you can do that by showing its derivative is negative when $0<x<1$.  That implies
$$
X + \frac 1 X \le y \text{ if and only if } X \ge \frac{y - \sqrt{y^2-4}} 2. \tag 1
$$
The probability of that is
$$ 1 - \frac{y - \sqrt{y^2-4}} 2.$$

That gives you the c.d.f. and if you need the p.d.f. you can differentiate.

Comment: Thank you, that was crystal clear.

Comment: @learner : I'm glad it helped. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

The function $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$, so it's enough to find where $x+\frac{1}{x}=y$, since then $P(Y<y)$ is equal to $1$ minus that value.  We can find that value from the quadratic formula
$$
\frac{y-\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2}
$$

So, $P(Y<y)=1-\frac{y-\sqrt{y^2-4}}{2}$ for $y>2$ and $0$ for $y\leq2$